# Multiple functions in restify function to elasticsearch client

Tags: rest, elasticsearch, restify, elasticsearch-api

I'm building a REST API using node and restify that communicaties with an elasticsearch database. Now when I delete an object, I want this to do a kind of cascading delete to some other objects. I know this is not really what to use elasticsearch for but bear with me.

So here is my code:

```
function deleteHostname(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    var endpoints = [];

    client.search({
        index: 'test',
        type: 'something',
        body: {
            from: 0, size: 100,
            query: {
                match: {
                    hostname: 'www.test.com'
                }
            }
        }
    }).then(function (error, resp) {
        if(error) {
            res.send(error);
        }

        endpoints = resp.hits.hits;

        for (index = 0, len = endpoints.length; index < len; ++index) {
            client.delete({
                index: 'test',
                type: 'something',
                id: endpoints[index]._id
            }, function (error, response) {
                if(error) {
                    res.send(error);
                }
            });
        }

        res.send(endpoints);
        return next();
    });
}
```

So basically I just want to search for any objects with hostname www.test.com ( I just hard coded this to test it ). Then I want to delete all objects I found. It follows the error path and sends me this:

```
{  
   "took":1,
   "timed_out":false,
   "_shards":{  
      "total":5,
      "successful":5,
      "failed":0
   },
   "hits":{  
      "total":1,
      "max_score":2.098612,
      "hits":[  
         {  
            "_index":"test",
            "_type":"something",
            "_id":"123456",
            "_score":2.098612,
            "_source":{  
               "duration":107182,
               "date":"2016-05-04 00:54:43",
               "isExceptional":true,
               "hostname":"www.test.com",
               "eta":613,
               "hasWarnings":false,
               "grade":"A+",
               "ipAddress":"ipip",
               "progress":100,
               "delegation":2,
               "statusMessage":"Ready"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

So in my opinion this doesn't look like an error? So why am I getting it back as an error? If I remove:

```
        if(error) {
            res.send(error);
        }
```

From my code, I won't get any response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your code like this (see the changes denoted by `->` to the left):

```
    if(error) {
1->     return res.send(error);
    }

    endpoints = resp.hits.hits;

    for (index = 0, len = endpoints.length; index < len; ++index) {
2->     (function(id){
            client.delete({
                index: 'test',
                type: 'something',
3->             id: id
            }, function (error, response) {
                if(error) {
4->                 next(error);
                }
            });
5->     })(endpoints[index._id]);
    }

6-> //res.send(endpoints);
```

I'm now explaining each change:

1. If you don't `return` you'll send the error and then you'll continue with processing the hits
2. (3/5) Since `client.delete` is an asynchronous function, you need to call it in an anonymous function
3. In case of error you need to call `next(error)` not `res.send`
4. You cannot send the response at this point since your for loop might not be terminated yet. Instead of a for loop, you should use the excellent [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) library instead (see an example of using [`asynch.each`](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachcoll-iteratee-callback) below)

Async example:

```
    var async = require('async');
    ...

    if(error) {
        return res.send(error);
    }

    endpoints = resp.hits.hits;

    async.each(endpoints, 
        function(endpoint, callback) {
            client.delete({
               index: 'test',
               type: 'something',
               id: endpoint._id
            }, callback);
        }, 
        // this is called when all deletes are done
        function(err){
            if (err) {
                next(err);
            } else {
                res.send(endpoints);
                next();
            }
        }
    );
```

Another solution for you to achieve exactly what you want is to use the [delete by query plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.3/plugins-delete-by-query.html). That feature allows you to do all the above in a single query.

If you are still on ES 1.x, delete-by-query is still part of the core and you can simply call the [`deleteByQuery` function](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference-1-7.html#api-deletebyquery-1-7) of the Javascript client.

If you are on ES 2.x, delete-by-query is now a plugin, so yo need to [install it](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.3/plugins-delete-by-query.html) and then also require the [deleteByQuery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch-deletebyquery) extension library for the Javascript client

```
function deleteHostname(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    client.deleteByQuery({
        index: 'test',
        type: 'something',
        body: {
           query: {
               match: { hostname: 'www.test.com' }
           }
        }
    }, function (error, response) {
        if (error) {
            next(error);
        } else {
            res.send(endpoints);
            next();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Ok so I had to change one more thing, for some reason it was always giving me an error while it was actually the response so I changed .then(function (error, resp) { to .then(function(resp) { to just give me the response and now it works!

Comment: Oh yes, good point, I missed that, the then callback doesn't have any error argument.